# Clarification of Git cherry-pick command?

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have following Branches

> a) Master

> b) Master/Test-1

> c) Master/Test-2

I have few commits on **Master/Test-1** branch.
I had cherry-pick on  **Master/Test-2** branch from above commit hash.
if i delete **Master/Test-1** branch.
Is cherry-pick changes will be present on **Master/Test-2** or not ?

Comment: You see how when you cherry-picked, the new commit got a new hash? Then it's a new commit, separate from the old one. And since it's referenced by a branch, it will remain in existence.

Answer (score 2):

While there is any reference to commit, git not remove this commit.